# Changing a ForeignKey to a be the parent class/model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a situation where there are various entities, with ForeignKeys to models that are subclasses of another model.  I need to update these FKs to point to the parent, so that any of the various subclasses could be linked.

For example, the code might be:

```
class School(Model):
    ...

class University(School):
    ...

class Student(Model):
    university = ForeignKey(University)
```

... and I need to change that FK from Student to University, to be an FK to School.

I think that all Universities will have the same ID as the School that is in the database for that university.  So is it safe/reliable to define the Student:

```
class Student(Model):
    university = ForeignKey(University)
    school = ForeignKey(School)
```

Then make a migration that creates the new `school` attribute, and uses RunPython to copy the id from `university` into `school`, then delete the `university` attribute and makemigrations for that?

Is it ever possible that this method would break, or produce bad data?

Comment: Yes your approach should be fine, since `University` will have an implicit one to one relation with `School`